# Wrong SHA1 in c++ OPENSSL

Tags: c++, openssl, sha1, sha

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? I'm trying to print SHA1 hash for "12345" but it displays the wrong one, I can't figure out what is the problem in the code

```
int main() {

string smth = "12345";

unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA_CTX sha1;
SHA_Init(&sha1);
SHA_Update(&sha1, smth.c_str(), smth.length());
SHA_Final(hash, &sha1);
stringstream ss;

for (int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
{
    ss << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)hash[i];
}
cout << ss.str() << endl; }
```

The hash I've got:

```
f7e507be49c187214406fd2556302ba47d535780
```

Correct hash:

```
8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA_* functions calculate SHA-0 sum. Replace all functions with SHA1_* alternatives to calculate SHA-1.

Comment: damn i feel dumb right now - but is to be expected when you're not familiar with something. Thanks a lot!